# Error when trying to read multiple sheets from excel file

Tags: python, pandas

In the following code I'm trying to write multiple sheets from an Excel file,remove the empty cells, group the columns and store the result in another excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
sheets = ['R9_14062021','LOGS R9','LOGS R7 01032021']
df = pd.read_excel('LOGS.xlsx',sheet_name = sheets )
df.dropna(inplace = True)
df['Dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dt']).dt.date
df1 = df.groupby(['Dt','webApp','mw'])['chgtCh','accessRecordModule','playerPlay 
startOver','playerPlay PdL','playerPlay 
PVR','contentHasAds','pdlComplete','lirePdl','lireVod'].sum()
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
df1.to_excel(r'logs1.xlsx', index = False)
```

When I execute my script iget the following error:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'dropna'

how can I fix it?

Comment: use a `for` iter to iterate sheets. `for sheet in sheets: df = pd.read_excel('LOGS.xlsx',sheet_name = sheet ); df_list.append(df.dropna())`

Answer (score 0):

Taken from pandas documentation for [pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

[image]

If you give `sheet_name` a list, you will receive a list of dataframes.
Meaning you'll have to go over each dataframe and `dropna()` separately because you can't `dropna()` on a dictionary, your code will look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
sheets = ['R9_14062021','LOGS R9','LOGS R7 01032021']
dfs_list = pd.read_excel('LOGS.xlsx',sheet_name = sheets )
for i in dfs_list:
    df = dfs_list[i]
    df.dropna(inplace = True)
    df['Dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dt']).dt.date
    df1 = df.groupby(['Dt','webApp','mw'])['chgtCh','accessRecordModule','playerPlay 
startOver','playerPlay PdL','playerPlay 
PVR','contentHasAds','pdlComplete','lirePdl','lireVod'].sum()

    df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df1.to_excel(r'logs1.xlsx', index = False)
```

The main difference here is the usage of

```
for i in dfs_list:
    df = dfs_list[i]
```

in order to apply each change you are doing to **each** dataframe, if you want a specific dataframe you should do: `df[0].dropna()` for example.

Hope this helps and this is what you were aiming for.

Comment: hello, first thanks for taking the time for answering my question, when I tried your script it giveme this error

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Comment: My bad, it was an iterating problem. Fixed now using `df = dfs_list[i]`

Comment: I tried it but in the end I got an excel file withe one empty sheet

Comment: Not sure I understand, could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a list of sheets for `sheet_name` param, your return object is dict of DataFrame [as described here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

`dropna` is method of DataFrame so you have to select the sheet first. for example

```
df['R9_14062021'].dropna(inplace=True)
```